# How can I move an app from one space to another?

Tags: swisscomdev

I have created a new space in the organisation and I have to move several apps from one space to the newly created one. How can I do this? (I don't want to rename the old space since only a subset of its apps need to be moved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid there is no such function to move apps from one space to another. There are two possibilities to achieve it, though:

## Compile & Push

If you have access to the source-code of the app and use a common CI/CD setup, simply adjust your scripts, have them point to the new space and trigger a complete CI/CD cycle.

## Download & Push

If you don't have access to the source-code, the binary-repository where you store your binaries **or** have to ensure it is 100% the same droplet in the new space, you can download that droplet from Cloud Foundry and push it to the new space:

1. `cf app source-app --guid` to get your source app guid
2. `cf curl /v2/apps/:source-guid/droplet/download --output /tmp/droplet.tgz` to download the source app's droplet to your local machine (note that if your Cloud Controller is configured to use a remote blobstore this command will return a redirect to the actual location of the droplet)
3. `cf target -s destination-space` to target the space you want to push the copied droplet to
4. `cf push --droplet /tmp/droplet.tgz destination-app-name`

*Credits: [Github](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/cli/issues/1498#issuecomment-444211657)*

This will work for buildpack-based apps but not for Docker-based apps, as you can't simply download docker-binaries.

**Pitfall**: If you want to use the same route again, don't forget to delete (not just unbind) it from your old space.